# MATLAB Hamming-window

Tags: matlab, octave

I am using Hamming window using the first principle equation to produce a window of length 23. Below is the code that I am using:

```
>> M=23
>> w = .54 - .46*cos(pi*(0:M-1)'/M)
>> plot(w)
```

Why is the graph not displaying a popper Hamming window please? 
Attached are the equation I am using and the output for this code.
Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your n is going from 0 to M-1 not from -M to M

Try this instead:

```
M = 23
w = .54 + .46*cos(pi*(-M:M)/M)
plot(w)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The code you provided gave an inverted hamming window. Also, why the length being twice that of M? (i.e. the length of the window is  being plotted as 46, which is twice of the value provided for M)

Comment: The inverted window is due to the `-` sign before the `0.46` instead of the `+` . Also, the length is twice the value of `M` because n goes from -M to 1 and then from 1 to M, hence this corresponds to a length twice the value of M.

Comment: Is there a way to eliminate the length being twice the value of M please?

Comment: No there isn't as n is going from -M to M which is of length 2 M. I've updated my answer above to fix the inversion issue if you think it's correct please set it as the correct answer.